# looping on variable in python subprocess.run

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

Team: am unable to get the var aNode
substituted and executed along the kubectl get node aNode

I want my command to get translated as

```
kubectl get node node123
```

looping on var within python subprocess.run

```
                if gpustr in aNode:
                    os.environ['KUBECONFIG']=homedir+"/deployments/sjc4/bm/dev/jamkong.com"
                    subprocess.run(['kubectl get node', aNode], shell=True, encoding='utf-8', capture_output=False)
                else:
                    print(aNode, "is not a gpu but DeS")
```

any hints?

output:

```
lists me all the nodes instead of just aNode, that is node123 below
```

```
node123 11.11.1.1
node456 22.22.1.1
node789 33.33.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out using an alternate approach. but if anyone can explain why passing list to subprocess is not working would be helpful.

```
 cmd_str = f'kubectl get node {aNode}'
                    print(cmd_str)
                    subprocess.run(cmd_str,shell=True)
```

output

```
NAME             STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
node123   Ready    <none>   19d   v1.13.5
```